# Golang: mocking AWS services which have same method name

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, interface

I'm using two AWS services, Glue and DynamoDB and both of these services, have a same method name `CreateTable` so while mocking these services, I'm getting `CreateTable is ambiguous` error.

Glue: CreateTable https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/glue/#Glue.CreateTable

DynamoDB: CreateTable https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.CreateTable

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Code:

```
type UpdateWorkflow struct {
    glueIface glueiface.GlueAPI
    dbIface   dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
    tableName string
}

func NewUpdateWorkflow(tableName string) *UpdateWorkflow {
    sess := sessions.NewSession()
    return &UpdateWorkflow{
        dbIface:   dynamodb.New(sess),
        glueIface: glue.New(sess),
        tableName: tableName,
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
// MockUpdateWorkflow is a mock implementation of gluetestutils and dynamodb service
type MockUpdateWorkflow struct {
    glueiface.GlueAPI
    dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
    mock.Mock
}

func setup() (*UpdateWorkflow, *MockUpdateWorkflow) {
    mockClient := new(MockUpdateWorkflow)
    mockServices := &UpdateWorkflow{
        glueIface: mockClient,
        dbIface:   mockClient,
        tableName: mockTableName,
    }
    return mockServices, mockClient
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are conflicting function names, you cannot embed interfaces, you have to use named fields:

```
type MockUpdateWorkflow struct {
    g glueiface.GlueAPI
    d dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
    mock.Mock
}

func setup() (*UpdateWorkflow, *MockUpdateWorkflow) {
    mockClient := new(MockUpdateWorkflow)
    mockServices := &UpdateWorkflow{
        glueIface: mockClient.g,
        dbIface:   mockClient.d,
        tableName: mockTableName,
    }
    return mockServices, mockClient
}
```